# How do you overcome the minimum cell size limit?

Tags: tables

UPDATE: Answered by David Carlisle in the comments.

I'm creating a table using tabular for which I'm using code to make all the columns the same width:

`\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.000000005cm}}`

The smallest column I'm using doesn't contain any text and is used as a color index. As you can see, I seem to have hit some kind of minimum size limit on cell width and this making the whole table far too large for the page.

Is there a way of ignoring the size limit?

EDIT: My current file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{bm,array}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.0000000000000000001cm}}

\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.75}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{tabular}{| C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C | C | C C |}
\hline
 && \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\cellcolor{red}} & \multicolumn{12}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\cellcolor{orange}} & \multicolumn{12}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\cellcolor{yellow}} & \multicolumn{12}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\cellcolor{green}} & \multicolumn{12}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue}} & \multicolumn{12}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\cellcolor{black}} & \multicolumn{12}{|c|}{}\\
 \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\tiny 1} & \multicolumn{9}{| l |}{\color{gray} \scriptsize Base x Multipliers} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize CO} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize PO} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize I} & \multicolumn{9}{| l |}{\color{gray} \scriptsize Base x Multipliers} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize CO} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize PO} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize I} & \multicolumn{9}{| l |}{\color{gray} \scriptsize Base x Multipliers} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize CO} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize PO} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize I} & \multicolumn{9}{| l |}{\color{gray} \scriptsize Base x Multipliers} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize CO} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize PO} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize I} & \multicolumn{9}{| l |}{\color{gray} \scriptsize Base x Multipliers} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize CO} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize PO} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize I} & \multicolumn{9}{| l |}{\color{gray} \scriptsize Base x Multipliers} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize CO} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize PO} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{gray} \scriptsize I}\\
 \hline
 & & \cellcolor{red} & & &\cellcolor{orange}&& &\cellcolor{yellow}&&&\cellcolor{green}&& &\cellcolor{blue}&&&\cellcolor{black}&& & \cellcolor{red} & & &\cellcolor{orange}&& &\cellcolor{yellow}&&&\cellcolor{green}&& &\cellcolor{blue}&&&\cellcolor{black}&&  & \cellcolor{red} & & &\cellcolor{orange}&& &\cellcolor{yellow}&&&\cellcolor{green}&& &\cellcolor{blue}&&&\cellcolor{black}&&  & \cellcolor{red} & & &\cellcolor{orange}&& &\cellcolor{yellow}&&&\cellcolor{green}&& &\cellcolor{blue}&&&\cellcolor{black}&&  & \cellcolor{red} & & &\cellcolor{orange}&& &\cellcolor{yellow}&&&\cellcolor{green}&& &\cellcolor{blue}&&&\cellcolor{black}&&  & \cellcolor{red} & & &\cellcolor{orange}&& &\cellcolor{yellow}&&&\cellcolor{green}&& &\cellcolor{blue}&&&\cellcolor{black}&&  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

The whole table has 30 more rows but this is the minimum you need to understand the problem. There is one type of cell in the whole table that's just a single column and contains only a colour. Ideally, I want this to be half the size it's currently printing out as.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! 0.000000005cm is, for TeX, the same thing as zero. Can you explain better the context where you'd want to use this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I don't understand why you need such narrow columns, please expand on that.

Comment: I would guess that you want to increase that width to some visible size but instead `\setlength\tabcolsep{..}` to some value less than its default value of 6pt (this controls the padding either side of each column)

Comment: Do you need a column of such width to write your current bank balance?

Comment: Do you really want a cell width of 0.0000000000000000001cm? That's way less than the diameter of a hydrogen atom (which is - roughly speaking - a billion times larger)!

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you want to increase that width to some visible size but instead

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{..}
```

to some value less than its default value of 6pt (this controls the padding either side of each column)